# Git Push Errors when pushing to Github

Tags: github, git-push, git-add, git

I have been tirelessly trying to push a file to Github from Git.
From incomplete loading processes to duplicate files--I need some serious help trying to rectify this issue.

The following are the error messages received:

```
$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXXX/REPOSITORYNAME.git'
```

And...

```
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

And finally...

```
$ git add .
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/XXXXX/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your final problem could be:

In windows:
command prompt from repository directory, in your case C:/Users/username/

```
cd .git
del index.lock
```

Comment: had you set the accurate oring path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your repo is not 'https://github.com/xxxx/REPOSITORYNAME.git'? Your origin master is set to this url. Switch it to the correct origin

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `error: src refspec master does not match any` when I did a push without committing. So all I had to do was to commit some files and then

```
git push -u origin master
```

This simply tells to remove index.lock file from the working tree and from the index in linux/unix/gitbash/cygwin.

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

If the above didn’t work try this one below.

```
rm .git/index.lock
```

That’s it that will do the trick

If it is Windows Command Prompt, try:

```
del .git\index.lock
```

if your git has crashed, then you have to run a

```
git reset
```

after you remove your index.lock file

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, and everybody else. Here is an additional error I'm experiencing: $ rm .git/index.lock
rm: cannot remove ‘.git/index.lock’: No such file or directory